# How to exclude a URL from HTTPS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have tried different links to see if it works, however it doesn't seems to work. I have configured https on Redhat EL6. However i wanted to have an exception from one of the IP.

I wanted to have https enabled for all except one IP 192.168.1.1. When i access the URL from the IP 192.168.1.1, it should get redirected or rewritten to http://cab.abc.com and not to https://cab.abc.com

**Snip of my /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf :**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /opt/app/cr/public
    ServerName cab.abc.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteLog /var/tmp/rewrite.log
    RewriteLogLevel 5
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^192\.168\.1\.1
    # RewriteRule .*  http://cab.abc.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R]
    # RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://cab.abc.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R]
    RewriteRule .* http://cab.abc.com [L]
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.*)
    RewriteRule .*  https://cab.abc.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R]
    # ProxyPass / https://cab.abc.com/
    # ProxyPassReverse / https://cab.abc.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

**I have tried multiple options and checked the rewrite.log file :**

```
192.1681.1 - - [21/Apr/2016:20:36:01 +0000] [cab.abc.com/sid#7fe3e21fe2e0][rid#7fe3e24c9b48/initial] (2) rewrite '/' -> 'http://cab.abc.com'
192.1681.1 - - [21/Apr/2016:20:36:01 +0000] [cab.abc.com/sid#7fe3e21fe2e0][rid#7fe3e24c9b48/initial] (2) implicitly forcing redirect (rc=302) with http://cab.abc.com
192.1681.1 - - [21/Apr/2016:20:36:01 +0000] [cab.abc.com/sid#7fe3e21fe2e0][rid#7fe3e24c9b48/initial] (1) escaping http://cab.abc.com for redirect
192.1681.1 - - [21/Apr/2016:20:36:01 +0000] [cab.abc.com/sid#7fe3e21fe2e0][rid#7fe3e24c9b48/initial] (1) redirect to http://cab.abc.com [REDIRECT/302]
192.1681.1 - - [21/Apr/2016:20:36:01 +0000] [cab.abc.com/sid#7fe3e21fe2e0][rid#7fe3e24c9b48/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /
192.1681.1 - - [21/Apr/2016:20:36:01 +0000] [cab.abc.com/sid#7fe3e21fe2e0][rid#7fe3e24c9b48/initial] (3) applying pattern '.*' to uri '/'
192.1681.1 - - [21/Apr/2016:20:36:01 +0000] [cab.abc.com/sid#7fe3e21fe2e0][rid#7fe3e24c9b48/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input=‘192.168.1.1’ pattern='^192\\.168\\.1\\.1’ => matched
192.1681.1 - - [21/Apr/2016:20:36:01 +0000] [cab.abc.com/sid#7fe3e21fe2e0][rid#7fe3e24c9b48/initial] (2) rewrite '/' -> 'http://cab.abc.com'
192.1681.1 - - [21/Apr/2016:20:36:01 +0000] [cab.abc.com/sid#7fe3e21fe2e0][rid#7fe3e24c9b48/initial] (2) implicitly forcing redirect (rc=302) with http://cab.abc.com
192.1681.1 - - [21/Apr/2016:20:36:01 +0000] [cab.abc.com/sid#7fe3e21fe2e0][rid#7fe3e24c9b48/initial] (1) escaping http://cab.abc.com for redirect
192.1681.1 - - [21/Apr/2016:20:36:01 +0000] [cab.abc.com/sid#7fe3e21fe2e0][rid#7fe3e24c9b48/initial] (1) redirect to http://cab.abc.com [REDIRECT/302]
192.1681.1 - - [21/Apr/2016:20:36:01 +0000] [cab.abc.com/sid#7fe3e21fe2e0][rid#7fe3e24c5b28/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /
192.1681.1 - - [21/Apr/2016:20:36:01 +0000] [cab.abc.com/sid#7fe3e21fe2e0][rid#7fe3e24c5b28/initial] (3) applying pattern '.*' to uri '/'
192.1681.1 - - [21/Apr/2016:20:36:01 +0000] [cab.abc.com/sid#7fe3e21fe2e0][rid#7fe3e24c5b28/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input=‘192.1681.1.’ pattern='^192\\.168\\.1\\.1’ => matched
```

Requesting your help to exclude an IP address from HTTPs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these rules after clearing browser cache:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=192.168.1.1
RewriteRule ^ https://cab.abc.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} =192.168.1.1
RewriteRule ^ http://cab.abc.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L,NE]
```

Comment: Posting it with Proper Format

Comment: Not Printing the page using http : 

# curl -k http://cab.abc.com
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://cab.abc.com">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>

Printing the page using https : 
# curl -k https://cab.abc.com is working fine.

Comment: Basically 192.168.1.1 is the same machine where the HTTPD is running. I have a cronjob which should be able to use the http://cab.ab.com URL from the same machine. :-)